# Encode Method RS256 in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, jwt, rsa, private-key

I have to do a native JWT Key Method, and i have to use RSA256 method, but when i try this :

```
$sha256 = hex2bin("3031300d060960864801650304020105000420").hash("sha256",$data,true);
$encrypt_rsa = openssl_private_encrypt($sha256, $partialEncrypted, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
$encrypted .= $partialEncrypted;
```

it return me that :

```
]YXzn_U]f
                   " >@ќw
                         -<Bt
                             TD6W7  y͜CE    ^fa~N5[l<%xn1b>Eh3j}0D,eL5]q}$Vpg
fq/;~g7>r0M3Հ$WMA;?Y̶g DA|v7܄C%wɑ7{mh L
```

and when i try to decode with that method :

```
$decrypt_rsa = openssl_public_decrypt($function_rsa, $partialDecrypted, $certificate, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
$decrypted .= $partialDecrypted;
```

it return me nothing.

I know there is an error in my encoding method but I don't kwow why.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at [openssl_error_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php) to find the error?

Comment: yes and it's empty

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

`$sha256` contains non-printable characters and should therefore be displayed with a proper encoding, e.g. hexadecimal using `bin2hex`. This also applies to `$encrypted`. `$function_rsa` is currently not defined. Assuming that it's a copy/paste error and `$function_rsa` corresponds to `$encrypted`, the code works, that is `$decrypted` equals `$sha256`:

```
<?php

// Create a test key pair
$keypair = openssl_pkey_new(array("private_key_bits" => 2048));
openssl_pkey_export($keypair, $privateKey);
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($keypair);
$publicKey = $publicKey["key"];

$data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

// Encrypt
$encrypted = "";
$sha256 = hex2bin("3031300d060960864801650304020105000420").hash("sha256", $data, true);
$encrypt_rsa = openssl_private_encrypt($sha256, $partialEncrypted, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
$encrypted .= $partialEncrypted;

// Decrypt
$decrypted = "";
$decrypt_rsa = openssl_public_decrypt($encrypted, $partialDecrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
$decrypted .= $partialDecrypted;

// Compare
print("Original data:  " . bin2hex($sha256) . "\nEncrypted data: " . bin2hex($encrypted) . "\nDecrypted data: " . bin2hex($decrypted));

?>
```

Another possible error source are of course the keys. Check this again if necessary.

The encryption of the hash with preceding hash ID corresponds to the signature of the data from which the hash was generated using RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5-padding ([RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2)). Note, that the signature of the data can be generated much easier with [`openssl_sign`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php):

```
$getPrivate = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $getPrivate, "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
print("\nSignature:      " . bin2hex($signature));
```